# OroPlatform: Open items from application_menu in a new tab

Tags: orocrm, orocommerce

Is it possible to configure some items from back-office's application_menu to open in a new browser tab?

[image]

There is an option called "Target Window" for frontend_menu but not for application_menu.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible with the `navigation.yml` configuration that is merged across all the installed bundles.

You can use the `link_attributes` option to specify the target _blank for the menu item link.

E.g.:

```
link_attributes:
  target: _blank
```

For more details on navigation.yml features, see [the OroNavigationBundle documentation](https://github.com/oroinc/platform/tree/4.2/src/Oro/Bundle/NavigationBundle).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a bug with "link_attributes"

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Cannot parse "Resources/config/oro/navigation.yml" configuration. 
Unrecognized option "link_attributes" under "navigation.menu_config.items.test_item". 
Did you mean "linkAttributes"?").
```

This works `linkAttributes`:

```
      test_item:
        label: 'Test Item'
        uri: 'link'
        linkAttributes:
          target: _blank
    tree:
      application_menu:
        children:
          ttttt:
            children:
              test_item: ~
```

Comment: Thank you, Boris. We will fix the documentation then. Next time, please report bugs directly to Oro repositories, where it's much easier to track them: https://doc.oroinc.com/community/issues/